# Symfony (Installation failed > <)

Tags: symfony

After awhile of consideration of choosing framework I started up with Symfony.While installation I try to fix of all t he recommended request until it left with ..

> Welcome to your new Symfony project.
>   This script will guide you through the
>   basic configuration of your project.
>   You can also do the same by editing
>   the ‘app/config/parameters.ini’ file
>   directly.
>   **Links at below** 
>  
>   Configure your Symfony Application online 
>   Bypass configuration and go to the Welcome
>   page Re-check configuration

So I try to choose "Bypass configuration and go to the Welcome page" and I get ugly page with all errors. With all "Notice require() bla bla" What should I do ??

Comment: Read the help pages? [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html)

Comment: The link u showing were assuming succeed in installation ?

Comment: That is a link to the complete Symfony reference. You will likely find the answer to your problem there, unless you want to sit on your hands and wait for someone to tell you an answer. I don't know Symfony, so I can't help you. Hence a "comment" instead of an "answer."

Comment: Well, for a start, you could post the whole error message. Otherwise it'll be difficult for us to bla bla.

Answer (score 0):

`require()` notices are usually either missing files or file permission errors. Make sure you downloaded Symfony2 with vendors if this is your first time.

Try running the `app/check.php` script to make sure that all the requirements that Symfony2 has are set up correctly. Common problems:

- `app/cache` and `app/logs` need to be writeable by the web server user. The simple (and bad) way to deal with this is to run `chmod -R a+rwX app/cache app/logs`
- Symfony2 requires the `intl` PHP extension. You can usually install it with something like `apt-get install php5-intl` or `yum install php5-intl`
- You must be running PHP 5.3.4 or newer

Comment: why are you saying that symfony2 require php 5.3.4, the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/requirements.html) specifies 5.3.2? I'm asking you this because I wonder if it could be my problem see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045647/symfony2-installation-error-non-existent-service-security-authentication-facto

Comment: My mistake; if the doc says 5.3.2 then that's what's right. The `app/check.php` will tell you if there's anything wrong with your setup.