# Symfony2 installation error: non-existent service "security.authentication.factory.form"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to install Symfony2 on my ubuntu 10.04 machine (32 bits) using these [steps](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html), but I keep getting this exception.

```
$./bin/vendors install
...
HEAD is now at 41b5913 Merge pull request #27 from stof/disable_profiler
PHP Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:  You have requested a non-existent service "security.authentication.factory.form". in /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 202
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/app/console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/app/console:22
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
PHP   4. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:66
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:80
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/app/bootstrap.php.cache:513
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/app/bootstrap.php.cache:779
PHP   8. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/app/bootstrap.php.cache:868
PHP   9. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:437
PHP  10. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:119
PHP  11. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:39
PHP  12. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension->load() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:42
PHP  13. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension->createListenerFactories() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php:49
PHP  14. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php:596
PHP  15. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /home/yvoyer/www/calendar.local/trunk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:316
Segmentation fault
```

I can't even see the default app.
I tried to install it with and without vendors, but I still get the same errors.

Any help is welcome

**Update:**

I tried to reinstall everything from scratch from the sources of 2.0.10 instead of 2.0.9, and I get the same error.

I succeed to setup Symfony2 with the same sources on another Pc (ubuntu 11.10 64 bits), without any errors.

- When running the app/check.php, Everything is OK except the PHP Accelerator. I don't see why it could be causing any problem since it run fine without it on my other machine.
- Does my php version could be the problem (5.3.2)?

Do you have any suggestions?

**Update #2**:

I tried to rebuild the `bootstrap.php.cache` file as suggested by inanimatt without any luck. I just noticed that the `./bin/vendors install` caused a segmentation fault, which I don't know if it were there before...

Also, I tracked down what command caused the problem in the vendors script. I found out that everything went fine until the script runs the `app/console assets:install`.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time trying all the above answers, I finally found what was the problem.

The problem was that I have **xdebug installed** on the server and the config `xdebug.show_exception_trace` was set to 1. This showed me every exceptions that happened, and resulted in the stack trace above.

I commented the line, and everything went as usual when configuring the application.

Thanks to those who helped me, and I hope this could help someone else.

Comment: This is exactly the same problem I had. Thanks for the answer. Removing `xdebug.show_exception_trace` is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear your cache
2. Do the: php app/config-check
3. Check the configuration of the: https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle
4. Check the yourvhost/check.php to check required php libs

Regards,
Max

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried all the things you said, except for 3. I don't see any reference to https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle in the deps file, is it suppose to be there?

Answer (score 0):

The error above seems to be that there's stuff missing from the bootstrap cache, which is failing the tasks that the `bin/vendors install` script runs. Try to delete that file and rebuild it by running:

```
php vendor/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Why that's happening is hard to know from here - have you modified any of the configuration files?

If you install the Symfony2 Standard Edition with vendors, you don't need to ever run `bin/vendors install`. You only need to run `app/check.php` to make sure the system settings and file permissions are fine, and then edit `app/config/parameters.ini` to set up your database.

Comment: originaly I installed Symfony with vendors, and maybe I runned the `bin/vendors` script (that I don't recall). After seeing this error, I wiped out all the directory, and re-installed Symfony from the tar without vendors, and still got this issue. This is why I wonder if its not related to the php version, or a misconfigured server... By the way, Thanks I will try that.